# how to remove this pin/nail

Tags: removal, rivets

I want to open a cheap small toast oven for a project. Any idea how to cleanly remove this pin in this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That looks like a pop rivet. Remove it by using a drill bit.

Comment: Note that you'll want the bit to be the size of the pin in the center. Bigger than the hole (obviously), but smaller than the domed part.

Comment: Also note that this will destroy the rivet. That's the only way to get it out, but you'll need a new one (and the tool to install it) if you want to put the toaster oven back together the same way.

Comment: Alternately if you're ok abusing the tools you have but don't have a drill, a hammer and flat blade screwdriver misused as a chisel should work .

Comment: If the rivet spins while you’re drilling it out, needlenose pliers can help hold the outside ring still.